# iOS 8 Custom Keyboard: self.inputView.bounds is still {0,0},{0,0} in viewDidLayoutSubviews in some cases

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, custom-keyboard

I'm creating an iOS 8 Custom Keyboard extension primarily using AutoLayout in my XIB. The last step of layout is adding the keyboard keys programmatically. To do this, I **need a valid width** to properly space keys.

Most StackOverflow posts and references I have read says to perform programmatic layout in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Most posts say that self.view / self.inputView will not have a valid size in `viewDidLoad` so `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is the right place to do it.

However, `self.inputView.bounds` and `self.view.bounds` (and `.frame`) give me 0 widths in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` in some cases.

**Oddly**, this only seems to happen in iPhone apps that Auto-Scale/Auto-Zoom for iPhone 6's form factor. Zynga's Words With Friends and my old version of Facebook seems to be one of these.

Can anyone help with this? Why would the `inputView`'s bounds/frame ever be 0x0 in by the time `viewDidLayoutSubviews` gets called? Is there any other better method in which I should add components programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommand the using of `viewDidLayoutSubviews` for keyboard extension. In `viewDidLoad` it won't have a valid size but you **don't need a valid size to do this**. Because you know the size of your keyboard as long as you get the device model (orientation is another thing).

As for your question, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` along with `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is sometimes called many times. And `frame.bounds.width == 0` is also possible when the view is created. That's why I don't recommand using them. The reason I think is that the keyboard extension part of iOS 8 is still buggy and unstable.

If you really need to use `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, prevent it from getting wrongly called:

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    if (self.view.frame.size.width == 0 || self.view.frame.size.height == 0)
        return; 
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I have tried to use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]`, `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` etc., but these are giving me the native resolution instead of the scaled app resolution. Again, this seems to just be a problem for apps (like Zynga games and a few others) that were written for 5/5s and automatically up-scaled/zoomed for iPhone 6. So, if I use the device's resolution to get the width, it ends up yielding a keyboard that is too wide for the scaled-up app.

Comment: @user3934927 Have you tried `[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds]`? It won't change whether the app is in scale mode or not.

Comment: @user3934927 My solution for scaled apps is to force the keyboard using resolution of 5/5s once scaled detected.

Comment: skyline75489--for some reason, `nativeBounds` and `bounds` are the same for me, even in scaled apps. Also, `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]` always comes back as `2`. I haven't figured out why this is--I figured it was a bug in the Keyboard Extension framework.

Comment: @user3934927  `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]` being 2 indicates that it's running on a retina device(4/4s/5/5s/6). It will be 3 on 6 Plus because the resolution of 6 Plus is kinda special. Anyway, it has nothing to do with whether the app is in scale mode. A significant difference with scaled mode is that `self.view.frame.width` will be 320 (like it on 5/5s) instead of 375(normal mode on 6) or 414(normal mode on 6 Plus). You can use this to detect whether an app is running in scaled mode.